# File in selected file array md5 encryption with CryptoJS always gives the same md5 value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, file-upload, cryptojs

In my Vuejs front-end, there is a file upload button. When user selected the file Vuejs triggers the @change event.I have used the file reader and I have imported the Cryptojs libraries which I have downloaded as node modules(in npm).

```
import cryptoJs from '../../node_modules/crypto-js'
import md5 from '../../node_modules/crypto-js/md5'
```

My html code for file upload button as follows:

```
<input type="file" ref="uploadedfile" name="file1" id="file1" @change="handleFileUpload">
```

File reader code inside the @change function:

```
handleFileUpload(e){

const filesToRead = e.target.files;
//getting the first file from the files array
let file1 = filesToRead[0];

const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', (evt) => {

      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
        file1 = fileReader.result;
        const encryptedvalue = md5(cryptoJs.enc.Latin1.parse(file1)).toString();
        console.log("MD5 value is :");
        console.log(encryptedvalue);
      }
      
    });
}
```

But always I get the same md5 value although I selected different files.

In the file object array, I can see all the file related data also when I inspect through the Chrome developer tool's console.(If I console log as follows)

```
console.log(file1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code lacks the call that loads the data. This is probably just a copy/paste error. Since the data is parsed with the [Latin1](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) (aka ISO 8859-1) encoder, [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) is an appropriate method, e.g.:

```
handleFileUpload(e) {
  const filesToRead = e.target.files;
  let file1 = filesToRead[0];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
      file1 = fileReader.result;
      const encryptedvalue = md5(cryptoJs.enc.Latin1.parse(file1)).toString();
      console.log("MD5 value is :");
      console.log(encryptedvalue);
    }      
  });
  fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file1); // missing in the posted code
}
```

However, I cannot reproduce the problem with this code, neither locally nor online https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-fast-cx9gz (if in the online case the error message *C is undefined* is displayed, this can generally be eliminated by commenting out and in the two CryptoJS import lines in *components/Repro* - no idea why this happens).

---

However, I can reproduce the issue when the data is loaded with [`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer). If the `ArrayBuffer` is then parsed with the Latin1 encoder (as in the posted code), which is incompatible for this, then for *different* files always the *same* hash results. The result is correct again if the `WordArray` is created directly from the `ArrayBuffer` with:

```
const encryptedvalue = md5(cryptoJs.lib.WordArray.create(file1)).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. Yes, I have missed that code part. I have done a mistake from my side which is I have used readAsDataURL instead of fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file1);

Comment: Apart from this I noticed something inside the fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', (evt) => {} I need to access the initialized value outside that block. But I cannot access the value although I have defined the variable outside the block as: let mdvalue; then tried to access it outside the  fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', (evt) => {} and cannot access the value.

Comment: @CodeCanyon - Possibly it's related to the _asynchronous_ execution of the callback function, which is executed _temporally after_ the consumption of `mdvalue` in the outside block, so that the changed value is not yet available when it is requested. Perhaps you'll have to modify your design. Unfortunately, this can't be clarified in the context of comments. You should ask a new question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (e.g. without the encryption issue, unless it is mandatory for a repro). If necessary, you can refer to this answer.

Comment: Ok, got it. I will check whether my design is affected to this and will try to change it if so. Thanks!